# EaselJS custom font lineheight cross browser issues

Tags: javascript, fonts, easeljs

I'm having a few issues with the positioning of text looking vastly different in different browsers with Easel JS when embedding a custom font.

I think it may be the line height, but there is no way to control this with EaselJS as far as I am aware.

I have tried changing the `line-height` as well as some other properties of the body in CSS and in the font-face declaration but had no success!

[image: font]

as you can see it is only Firefox causing any problems, It also appears correctly (like chrome, IE and Safari) on multiple mobile and tablet devices, iOS and Android, (Chrome, Safari and Android native browsers)

On a previous project I had Firefox detection and setting the x position lower to balance it out, but i'm looking for a solution not a workaround!

---

EDIT: I stumbled across this [Why does my custom font have a positional offset in some browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220937/why-does-my-custom-font-have-a-positional-offset-in-some-browsers?rq=1)

But when I have text in the html, not rendered by EaselJS in canvas, there is no difference between browsers!

Comment: Can you provide some code? Maybe jsfiddle? It'll help you get some feedback/answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following font attributes are available on the drawing context (canvas):

- font can be anything you would put in a CSS font rule. That includes font style, font variant, font weight, font size, line height, and font family.
- textAlign controls text alignment. It is similar (but not identical) to a CSS text-align rule. Possible values are start, end, left, right, and center.
- textBaseline controls where the text is drawn relative to the starting point. Possible values are top, hanging, middle, alphabetic, ideographic, or bottom.

When drawing to the canvas set the textBaseline explicitly (js):

```
context.textBaseline = "alphabetic";
```

http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html

Did you try the text-rendering declaration? (css)

```
text-rendering: geometricPrecision;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering

Disclaimer: These are just wild guesses since you didn't supply any code.

Comment: Wow. I assumed textBaseline would move the position of the text relative to its default position, so didn't test. Now I feel stupid. I could kiss you, thanks!

Comment: Thats how I thought of it also. Just to align script type x to type y. Not realizing the consequences. But now I think of textBaseline as 'positioning anchor'. Which is the same but fits my brain. You're welcome. Happy coding!