# Webfont position rendering issue

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I'm using a customized webfont on my page and I'm having some rendering issues in different platforms. The alignment of the text in the blocks is somewhat different in linux and windows. Here's an example:

Chrome in Linux:
[image]

Chrome in Windows:
[image]

They're both using the same version of the font (otf), the styles are exactly the same (same line-height and margins).

Here's the source of the font-face:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Calibre Regular';
  src: url('fonts/Calibre-Regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('Calibre-Regular.otf')  format('opentype'),
       url('fonts/Calibre-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
       url('fonts/Calibre-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype'),
       url('fonts/Calibre-Regular.svg#Calibre-Regular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: It depends if they are both using the same version of the font - ie one may use the svg version and the other may use the woff version, in which case they will render differently.  You then need to check the default line height and vertical alignment of the element are the same - the line height looks the same but one looks to be vertically aligned to the middle and one to the top

Comment: I had this issue as well, I finally found it out myself and it might be to some use of you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7220937/why-does-my-custom-font-have-a-positional-offset-in-some-browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I think it's some problem with the font itself, the styles of the elements are exactly the same (using reset), the font files too. However, there are some errors when converting it manually, like Gerar suggested, I'll look into those errors and try to make new files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is can be caused by webkit when rendering custom fonts try using `-webkit-font-smoothing`. The default value of which is `subpixel-antialiased`. Try setting:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

**Alternative solution**

If the above doesn't work then this may work, I had a similar issue before with chrome and randomly found this fix on the interent. Not sure where but it basically forces Chrome to use the SVG version of the font.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'nameOfFontFamily';
        src: font-url('url/to/svgfont.svg') format('svg');
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that without success, I think there is some problem with the font itself.

Comment: @GuilhermeVierno - I have had a similar issue before, which I thought was due to the font itself, however I found a weird fix for it. I have edited the solution above to include this. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes! The alternative solution works like a charm. Thank you very much! It's a really weird fix...

Comment: @GuilhermeVierno glad it worked for you :) yes, very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers render elements different - could be the issue even if its the same browser. Define margin, padding and line-height in your CSS - you could use a 'reset.css'.

Try this:

```
p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
```

Comment: I'm using bootstrap's reset, the style of the elements are the same.